# How to access the given stringified data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, servlets

I am trying to access the data I passed from a Javascript array, to Java servlet and back to Javascript but I am getting "undefined".

Below is my Javascript code:

```
var buildingNo = [];
// Assuming the buildingNo's values are the following:
buildingNo = 12345, 54321;

$.ajax ({
   url: env + "/webaapp/myTestWeb/myTestEarFile",
   timeout:0,
   cache: false,
   data: {postalCode: postalCode, buildingNo: JSON.stringify(buildingNo)},
   success:function(data){
   alert(data); 
   //The output of this data is below: 
   //[{"status":"A";"buildingNo":"[\12345\",\"54321\"]"}]

   var jsonParse = JSON.parse(data);
   alert(jsonParse.status); // This gives out undefined.
   }
});
```

Here is the Java Servlet code snippet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

String postalCode = request.getParameter("postalCode");
String buildingNo = request.getParameter("buildingNo");

String status = "A";

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

jsonObj.put("status",status);
jsonObj.put("buildingNo",buildingNo);

jArray.add(jsonObj);

response.getWriter().write(jArray.toString());
}
```

How do I get the value of status, buildingNo separately for usage in Javascript?

Comment: [{"status":"A";"buildingNo":"[\12345\",\"54321\"]"}] is not a valid JSON

Comment: try any JSON formatter to verify the same e.g https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: How do I make it a valid JSON? Is the way of passing the Javascript array to Java servlet incorrect? or do I make changes inside the Java servlet?

Comment: You need to make changed to Java Servlet and need to pass valid JSON to javascript

Comment: Your servlet is fine. Isn't it just a typo/copy-paste error? Are you sure that's the data you're getting back?

Comment: Hi @RobbyCornelissen, yes, the alerts in the code are the output I'm getting.

Comment: So your servlet is returning `[{"status":"A";"buildingNo":"[\12345\",\"54321\"]"}]`? That seems highly unlikely. Given your servlet code, that should be `[{"status":"A","buildingNo":"[\"12345\",\"54321\"]"}]`. Also, if your servlet really returned the above JSON, you'd get an error on trying to parse it.

Comment: buildingNo: JSON.stringify(buildingNo) ? what is the value of buildingNo here? That may causing the problem. Are you passing in array or comma seperated as shown in your example?

Comment: @Narendra: Nothing wrong with passing a stringified array as a JSON property, but obviously the code in the question that says `buildingNo = 12345, 54321;` is wrong. We're being led on a wild goose chase and are just wasting our time here as long as OP fails to provide a decent [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cutting through all the code errors in the question, the JSON returned by the servlet is very likely to be correct. If not, `JSON.parse()` would throw an error and you would not get an undefined value on outputting `jsonParse.status`.

Then the real issue is that your servlet is sending you an array, so you need to treat it as one:

```js
const jsonParse = [{"status":"A","buildingNo":"[\"12345\",\"54321\"]"}];

console.log(jsonParse[0].status); // "A"
```

Comment: Yes it's indeed sending an array. Got the values using your code. Thanks so much!